# How to link specific user to instance id

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-authentication

I have android app that uses firebase authentication to authenticate users. After sign up I send user information to my backend (python/flask) and save that information to database.

Now I need to send notification to specific user from backend, but how can I know which instance id belongs for user? Currently there's no link between user id and instance id. How can I link these together? Instance id is created and send to backend on app start, before user is signed in.

Comment: But what do you mean by user id? You can simply post your instance id from app to server. What are you doing to save users?

Comment: By user id I mean Firebase user uid. Yes I can post instance id to server, but how can I link it to specific user? After registration I save user additional information to my database (firebase_uid, nickname, age etc.).

Comment: For example, I need to send push notification for user that nickname is John (user in database), how can I figure out John's instance id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to maintain a mapping between uid and iid. So everytime a user signs in you maintain a key/value map of uid: [all iids from different devices] on your backend. Make sure you send the Firebase ID token and get the uid from there after verifying the token. You will need to maintain that mapping. If the user signs out or a Firebase session is invalidated for various reasons (user disabled, deleted or password reset, etc), unlink that iid from the uid and if an iid is invalidated, remove it from the mapping.
When you need to send a push notification to a user identified by uid, you would look up the list of iid tokens and send a notification to each one.

Comment: Ok. How can I detect when iid is invalidated, so I can send it to backend and unlink that iid from the uid?

Comment: They have public methods to delete a token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId#public-methods and a listener to token refresh: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService#public-methods

Comment: What if user sign in (link created between iid and uid) and then delete & re-install app (new iid created). Will there be a obsolete link between iid and uid?

Comment: Yes that will be the case. You may want to do some clean up every certain period of time to remove stale mappings.